# SQL WHERE <input value> = $variable

Tags: sql

I can't get this work:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO products (quantity, location) VALUES ('$quantity', '$location') WHERE 'sku'=$sku";
```

I am pretty sure it's a syntax error, but can't figure it out alone.

I want to update quantity and location fields in the table only in those rows where "SKU" input value = SKU in the table row.

Comment: is it for sql server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`INSERT` statement attempts to add a row. `WHERE` clause is not valid on an `INSERT ... VALUES` statement.

To modify an existing row, we can use `UPDATE` statement.

```
UPDATE products p
   SET p.quantity  = ?
     , p.location  = ?
 WHERE p.sku  = ?
```

With MySQL... if we have a unique constraint on the `sku` column, and we want to update a row if it already exists, or add a row if it does not exist, then we could also use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` statement, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO products (sku, quantity, location) VALUES ( ? , ? , ? )
  ON DUPLICATE KEY
  UPDATE quantity = VALUES(quantity)
       , location = VALUES(location)
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: thanks for your reply, but in your example above, what "p" stands for?

Comment: `p` is a short alias assigned (within the SELECT statement) to the table reference `products`.  Column references can then be qualified with the short alias `p.sku` rather than the longer table name `products.sku`. The ANSI SQL Standard calls it a "correlation name".

Comment: Also, any potentially unsafe values that are incorporated into SQL text *must* be properly escaped. A better pattern is to use prepared statements with bind placeholders.  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection